# Get Type of nested Generic, create new Object of that Type

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, casting

Is there a good way to achieve the following? Basic idea is have a generic method that may take a List as T, get the Type of J and create a new List within the method. And further create an instance of J.

It is not enough to generate a

```
Type t = typeof(T).GetGenericArguments().Single();


// I need this
public static void foo<T>(T obj)
{
    // For this specific Example T is List<nestedType>
    // Create new List of nestedType but nestedType may be any Class
    List<nestedType> = new List<nestedType>();
    nestedType o = new nestedType();
}
```

What i have achieved so far

```
public static void foo<T>(T obj)
{
   var t = typeof(T); 
   if(t.GetInterfaces().Any(x => x.IsGenericType && x.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IList<>)))
        {
            Type underlyingType = t.GetGenericArguments().Single();
            dynamic varOfUnderlyingType = Convert.ChangeType(??, underlyingType);
        }
}
```

Comment: I'm confused.  What is `J` in your question?

Comment: foo<List<J>>(someList); so J will be the type in the List

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this? What are you expecting to know at compile time?

Comment: Ive read that but you can't use the Type and write List<typeVariable> sadly

Comment: So you don't just want types.Cast<nestedType>()?

Comment: No it is not, i changed the answer and hope that clarifies a bit what im trying to achieve.

Comment: I'm still confused - can you provide a concrete example - e.g. I have a `List<type1>` and want a `List<type2>` (with actual types for `type1` and `type2`) - that shows the relationship between the two types?  I'm not sure waht you mean by "nested type".

Comment: Is type T always a List of something?